# jQuery Plugins within <div> loaded with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using a design where there is the base page (a menu on the top and to the left), and all of the content pages are simply loaded into a container div when needed.

This works perfectly for how I want the site to flow, however about 20% of the time when loading a page into the div, jQuery plugins (such as datetimepicker, checktree, etc.) will not work, saying that e.g. '$(...).datetimepicker is undefined'.

Why would this be happening? Is there a way to make it more consistent? All of the necessary JS and CSS files are included, so I'm not sure why sometimes the plugins randomly won't work.

For reference, here is the page loading function:

```
function loadNewPage(page) {
    $("#maindiv").html("<center><img src='../assets/images/loading.gif'></center>");
    $.get(page, function(data) {
        $("#maindiv").html(data);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
}
```

Here is an example load function on one of the pages being loaded into the div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#beginDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $('#endDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

    $('#datatable').dataTable(
        {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "order": [20, 'desc'],
            "search": {
                "smart": false
            }
        }
    );
});
```

As I said, normally this all works just fine. However, occasionally (and seemingly randomly) the undefined error will pop up. This does not stop all functioning on the page, I can simply load the page again with the 'loadNewPage' function and the jQuery plugins can work again. (but with the random chance of not working)

Comment: Show at-least some code so that we could recognize what exactly you are trying ..

Comment: I'm actually editing in some code now, should be in there in just a sec

Comment: Ugh center tags someone beat this fella ;-) (sorry couldn't resist)

Comment: Please forgive me Shawn! :P A lot of my code needs to be tidied up a bit, but this is definitely a problem that needs to be figured out before changing too much else.

Comment: Where is the code for initializing your `datetimepicker`? Where is the date picker -- in the loaded div on the main page?  Show us the relevant parts of the main page and loaded content.

Comment: Everything involving the plugins are loaded into the div. I'll add some more relevant code to the first post.

Comment: You're getting random errors because the document ready event fired before your asynchronous content loaded (with the plugin libraries). Load the plugin libraries on the main page.

Comment: Do you mean putting the JS and CSS references on the main page? I've actually tried including them both ways but still get the errors either way. Is there a way to prevent the ready function from firing early?

Comment: Can the `loadNewPage` function be called before the main page is completely loaded?

Comment: Typically, you load all library script (jQuery, plugins, etc) on the main page. When these are loaded the browser emits the ready event. Then any dynamic content can immediately use the libraries. The problem  with loading the library with the dynamic content is you need to wait for the libraries to finish loading then execute any script for that content.

Comment: No, `loadNewPage` is only ever called when a link in the menu is clicked.

Comment: @Jasen I actually just went through to make sure that nothing external was being loaded in the dynamic content, and found that a couple of things were. It seems that this fixed the problem completely. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting random errors because the document ready event fired before your asynchronous content loaded (with the plugin libraries).

Typically, you load all library script (jQuery, plugins, etc) on the main page. When these are loaded the browser emits the ready event. Then any dynamic content can immediately use the libraries.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="plugin.js"></script>    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // script libraries are loaded

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            // target element is loaded
            $("#dynamic").html(data);
            $("#target").plugin();
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

The problem with loading the library with the dynamic content is you need to wait for the libraries to finish loading then execute any script for that content -- a race condition.